# Javascript Getting values from dat.GUI

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

Hi so I have a code as follows for dat.GUI interface.

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();
var obj1 = { x: 5};
gui.add(obj1, 'x');
```

How do I get the value of x from the gui into a variable?
for example

```
var xval = (something that returns the value of x from the gui)
```

If I do `var xval = obj1;` and I did `console.log(xval)` then I would get this `Object {x=5}` Just wondering how to get the value of that 5 out into a variable.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to call the x component from the object just like you would with a geometry.

```
var xval = obj1.x;
```

Answer (score 3):

i am not worked with three.js in the past but in plain it would be for example:

```
var obj1 = { x: 5};
var xval = obj1.x;
console.log(xval);
```